# Find the difference of every rows pair of the same data.frame

Tags: r

I would like to calculate the difference of every other pair of rows. e.g. first from second, third from fourth etc.

Let's say I have `x <- c(1,3,4,7)`. I would like the result to be `c((3-1),(7-4))`.

I searched a lot and didn't find anything. I hope it is not a duplicate.

Comment: You can just do `diff(x)[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`

Comment: @Sotos Thank you very much. Exceptional workaround.

Comment: Also, `x[c(FALSE, TRUE)] - x[c(TRUE, FALSE)]`.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn the vector into a 2-row array and then use `diff` to compute the differences between rows, which in this case will be the difference between the second and first row since there are only two rows.

```
> v <- c(1,3,4,7)
> v
[1] 1 3 4 7
> m <- matrix(v, nrow = 2)
> m
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    4
[2,]    3    7
> diff(m)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    3
```

In one step, returning a vector:

```
> c(diff(matrix(v, nrow = 2)))
[1] 2 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Example shown using `iris` dataset. Use `lapply()` function to perform on a data frame. For difference in between consecutive rows, use `diff()`, then extract every alternative difference.

**Input**

```
df2 <- head(iris[,1:4])
df2
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
```

**Difference between consecutive rows**

```
data.frame(lapply(df2, function(x) diff(x)))
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1         -0.2        -0.5          0.0         0.0
# 2         -0.2         0.2         -0.1         0.0
# 3         -0.1        -0.1          0.2         0.0
# 4          0.4         0.5         -0.1         0.0
# 5          0.4         0.3          0.3         0.2
```

**Required Output**

Difference of Row 2nd and Row 1st, Difference of Row 4th and Row 3rd, and
Difference of Row 6th and Row 5th

```
data.frame(lapply(df2, function(x) diff(x)))[seq(1, nrow(df2), by = 2),]
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
# 1         -0.2        -0.5          0.0         0.0
# 3         -0.1        -0.1          0.2         0.0
# 5          0.4         0.3          0.3         0.2
```